# Behaviour of OutputResponse in ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Ok, I think this is not the best way to do this, so I'm open minded for every suggestion doing it in a better way.

The Question is why does `ListLinePlot` not plot all the data when it's inside `Manipulate`?

I created a dataset w/ and wo/ noise:

```
dataFunc[x_] := .5 Sin[x^2 + x]

dataRaw = Table[dataFunc[x], {x, 0, 2 π, .001}];
dataNoise = 
  Table[dataFunc[x] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {x, 0, 2 π, .001}];

Grid[{ListLinePlot /@ {dataRaw, dataNoise}}]
ListLinePlot[{dataNoise, dataRaw}]
```

[image: dataset wo/ and w/ noise]

I'm doing the built in low-pass filter with `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot[{LowpassFilter[dataNoise, ω, n], dataRaw}],
  {{ ω, .3}, .001, Pi, .001}, {{n, 100}, 1, 500, 1}]
```

[image]

Now I added my own low-pass filter:

```
discLowPass[T_, τ_] := 
  ToDiscreteTimeModel[ TransferFunctionModel[ 1/(1 + T s), s], τ]
```

And here it is:
Without the dataRaw it works

```
Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot[OutputResponse[discLowPass[T, τ], dataNoise]],
  {{T, .1}, .005, 25}, {{ τ, .005}, .001, .025}]
```

[image]

... but adding the signal without noise to the `ListLinePlot` it doesn't work anymore.
Why?

```
Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot[{ OutputResponse[discLowPass[T, τ], dataNoise], 
    dataRaw}],
  {{T, .1}, .005, 25}, {{ τ, .005}, .001, .025}]
```

[image]

It's just plotting the raw signal without the noise.

**EDIT**:
Using `Show` it works for the `OutputResponse`, too.

```
Manipulate[
  Show[{
    ListLinePlot[OutputResponse[discLowPass[T, τ], dataNoise]],
    ListLinePlot[dataRaw, PlotStyle -> Red]}],
  {{T, .25}, .005, 5, .005}, {{ τ, .01}, .001, .025}]
```

[image]

Comment: What you are actually plotting in the end is `ListLinePlot[dataRaw]`

Comment: @Öskå That's what I can see, yes, but what is with the Outputresponse? In the first case with LowpassFilter[] it works too, doesn't it?

Comment: The problem here is that `Manipulate[ ListLinePlot[{OutputResponse[discLowPass[T, \[Tau]], dataNoise]}], {{T, .1}, .005, 25}, {{\[Tau], .005}, .001, .025}]` is not being plotted for some reason.

Comment: @Öskå ... and the question is why is it not plotted, while it is plotted when I take the built in LowpassFilter instead of the OutputResponse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like noted in the comments the problem is that

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[{OutputResponse[discLowPass[T, τ], dataNoise]}],
             {{T, .1}, .005, 25}, {{τ, .005}, .001, .025}]
```

> [image]

doesn't work while the following works:

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[OutputResponse[discLowPass[T, τ], dataNoise]],
             {{T, .1}, .005, 25}, {{τ, .005}, .001, .025}]
```

> [image]

By looking into `OutputResponse[]` you can see that it's built as follow:

```
OutputResponse[discLowPass[0.1, 0.5], dataNoise] // Short
```

> {{-0.203869, -0.311799, -0.725601, <<6278>>, 0.765344, 1.17987, 0.143347}}

and that it's a `{1, 6284}` array.

Thus the following works:

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[{First@OutputResponse[discLowPass[T, τ], dataNoise], dataRaw}], 
             {{T, .1}, .005, 25}, {{τ, .005}, .001, .025}]
```

> [image]